# Prevent Duplicate Google Script Copy A File with Filenames from Range

Tags: google-apps-script

I can copy a file and rename new copy from spreasheet range. How to not create existing filename if I re-execute the script.

```
function copyDocs() {
  var file = SpreadsheetApp.openById('fileID-spreadsheet');
  var ss = file.getSheetByName('List');
  var data = ss.getRange(2,1,ss.getLastRow()-1,1).getValues();

  for (var i in data) {
    var drive = DriveApp.getFileById('fileID-template');
    drive.makeCopy(data[i][0]);
  };
}
```

Here is my final script based on the answers

```
function copyDocs() {
  try {
    let spread = SpreadsheetApp.openById('fileID-spreadsheet');
    let sheet = spread.getSheetByName('List');
    let data = sheet.getRange(2,1,sheet.getLastRow()-1,1).getValues();
    let file = DriveApp.getFileById('fileID-template');
    let folder = file.getParents().next();

    for( let i=0; i<data.length; i++ ) {
      let files = folder.getFilesByName(data[i][0]);
      if( !files.hasNext() ) {
        file.makeCopy(data[i][0],folder);
      }
    }
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there 1 and only 1 file with that name?  Do you want the copy in the same folder as the original?

Comment: Yes I have 1 template file in the same folder as the new files. It works, thank you very much for your generous answer @TheWizEd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Description**

Here is a simple example of copying a file but checking that a file of that name doesn't already exist.

This assumes the files are in a subfolder, the same folder as the template file.  It also assumes there can be only one file with the same file name.

I've used my files so you need to check any file/spreadsheet reference against your requirements.

**Script**

```
function copyDocs() {
  try {
    let spread = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    let sheet = spread.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    let data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
    let file = DriveApp.getFileById(spread.getId());
    let folder = file.getParents().next();

    for( let i=0; i<data.length; i++ ) {
      let files = folder.getFilesByName(data[i][0]);
      if( !files.hasNext() ) {
        file.makeCopy(data[i][0],folder);
      }
    }
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

**Reference**

- [File.getParents()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#getParents())
- [Folder.getFilesByName()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#getFilesByName(String))
- [File Iterator](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file-iterator)
- [File.makeCopy()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#makeCopy(String,Folder))

][4](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#makeCopy(String,Folder))

Comment: Your right, done